# How can we get the Scheduled Job's Apex class and cron expression by scheduled Job Name?

Tags: scheduled-apex, asyncapexjob

***Example:***

old developer scheduled an apex class by cron expression.But the scheduled job name is not given properly.

Then how can we know that apex class by job name **to verify what is that job doing**?

```
AccountSchedulableClass sch= new AccountSchedulableClass ();
String cronexpression = '0 0 0 ? * * *';
System.schedule('blah blah blah', cronexpression, sch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Using the below query we can get the APEX class & Cron Expression

> ```
> SELECT ApexClass.Name, Id, JobType, Status, CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name, CronTrigger.CronExpression 
> FROM AsyncApexJob 
> WHERE CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name='your job Name' 
> AND JobType='ScheduledApex'
> ```

'